# Trouble defining a selector meant to locate two types of trs

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, css-selectors

I've written two expressions to locate some elements from a webpage. The elements are within `tr` which are within a table. The problem is there are two types of `tr`'s like:

```
<tr class="even"> 
<tr class="odd">
```

I would like to fetch the content from both the types.

When I try using `.find_all()`, I get it working in the right way. However, when I go for `.select()`, I find it working as well but the thing is the selector looks illegible. Can I not make the selector more readable and concise?

Using `.find_all()`:

```
soup.find("table",class_="rightLinks").find_all("tr",class_=["even","odd"])
```

Using `.select()`:

```
soup.select("table.rightLinks tr.even, table.rightLinks tr.odd")
```

***How can I make the latter more readable and concise?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost there. Just simplify your logical or CSS selector (`,`).

```
soup.select("table.rightLinks tr.even,tr.odd"))
```

**ORIGINAL**

You can use a selector template to not repeat the common part `table.rightLinks tr.`.

```
selector_template = "table.rightLinks tr.{cls}"
soup.select(", ".join((selector_template.format(cls="even"), selector_template.format(cls="odd"))))
```

Are there only `even` and `odd` tr classes in the target table? If so, why not simply use `soup.select("table.rightLinks tr")`?

Comment: Nope, there are around 6 tr classes in that table but I'm only interested in that two tr's.